# problem in reading textbox value in li

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a ul as follows: It can`t read the text values neither with val() nor text().  Can anyone help please

```
<ul id="mylist">     
<li id="1"><input type = "text" value= "aaaaa" /></li>     
<li id="2"><input type = "text" value= "bbbb" /></li>
<li id="3"><input type = "text" value= "ccc" /></li>
<li id="5"><input type = "text" value= "dddd" /></li>

</ul><button id="Button1">Add Another2</button>
```

var values = [];
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Button1").click(function() {

```
            $( "#mylist li text").each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
            values.push($(this).text());

            });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#Button1").click(function() {

```
            var i = 0;
            var inputs = new Array();
            $("#mylist li").find("input").each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
            inputs[i] = $(this).val();
                i++;
            });

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ":" in jquery selector

```
$("#mylist li :text")
```